# How can I transform 1 property without cancelling other transforms in selector?

Tags: css, compass-sass

I was wondering if I have used transform on 2 properties - translateY and scale and only want to transition scale on hover do I still have to include the translateY property in my hover transform to prevent it being cancelled out or is there something I can do to prevent this? Also instead of transitioning transform can I transition just the scale? I'm currently using compass. If anyone can recommend how I can enhance this code it would be great.

**Example:**

```
.btn {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: grey;
    display: block;
    @include transform( translateY(-50%) scale(1) );
    @include transition( transform .3s ease-in-out ); // i don't want to transition all transform properties but instead just the scale???

    &:hover {
        @include transform(translateY(-50%) scale(1.1)); //do i really need to have translateY in here even when it doesn't change on hover???
    }
}
```

**Codepen**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BiGHl

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you'll need to keep the `translateY(-50%)` entry.

Since both the translate and the scale are inside of the `transform:` style, by not entering a translateY value on the hover state you're essentially telling it `translatey(0%)` which the transition animates.

The alternative is animating it via keyframes.